# Can FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging) reassign the same token id

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on FCM. I discovered that after sometime, FCM token get refreshed. Is it possible that previous token id may get assigned to other user or new user?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, Because token is generated based on the current timestamp therefore there are no chances of generating the same token again.